# make a matrix multiplication without loop when the matrix is stored with vectors

Tags: python, math, matrix

I'm trying to make a matrix/vector multiplication, but my matrix is stored in a way `@` operator cannot be used.
My matrix `Z` is actually a `list` on size `N` containing the columns of the matrix which are all `PETSc4py.Vec` of size `NN`, where `NN`≫`N` (eg. `NN=10000` and `N=10`). As `N` is small, I can make a `for` loop on it, so for instance, if I want to compute `r =Z.T @ u` with `u` a vector of size `NN`, I do

```py
r = np.zeros(N)
for i,z in enumerate(Z):
    r[i] = u * z  # scalar product
```

Now I have a vector `u` of size `N` and I want to make the multiplication `w = Z @ u`, I can't apply the same method because it would involve a loop of size `NN` which I'm trying to avoid.

I could convert my "matrix" `Z` to a NumPy matrix, but I'm also trying to avoid it...

I represented on the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlMzs.png) the way the matrix is stored. A red line represents a vector that should be read for a the matrix-vector multiplication.

[image: Description of the matrix-vector product]

Is there a mathematical way (or a magic trick !) to compute this operation without making the big loop ?

Thanks

Comment: Does PETSc4py lack a Matrix class? It seems odd for "the Portable, Extensible Toolkit for Scientific Computation" to lack a matrix class.

Comment: Can I ask why are you trying to avoid NumPy arrays? NumPy has a very good linear algebra module.

Comment: It looks like it _does_ have a [Mat class](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc4py-current/docs/apiref/petsc4py.PETSc.Mat-class.html) that implements . You should use that instead of a list of vectors. The `Mat` class doesn't have a `__matmul__()` to define the behavior of the `@` operator, but it does implement a `matMult()` method that is presumably what you're looking for

Comment: yes I know it has a matrix class, but the way I construct the "matrix" returns this list, but I should try to use the `Mat` class instead, you're right.
The problem is that in my functions, the size `N` is not known at the beginning (on different steps of the algorithm, I append a new vector to the list)

Comment: A simpler way to do it would be after the generation of the list, I convert it to a `Mat`, but I have not found yet an efficient way to do it...